# HttpPost or HttpGet for JsonResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, jsonresult

I am calling from jQuery $.ajax JsonResult actions from my controller.

**I can either use get or post for JsonResult, but are there some good practices regarding this?**

I and my colleagues use interchangeably these two, with no logic behind them.

for ActionResult, things is pretty clear: is it a page accessible from the browser? HttpGet. Is it some button on the page? HttpPost.

Comment: HTTP methods are largely based on semantics: use GET to retrieve a resource, use POST to create a resource. There is also PUT which is to replace a resource and PATCH to modify a resource, although technically they can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

We use the various methods of Http such as

Get  To Get the Resource
Post To Add the Resource
Patch To Modify  Resource
Delete To Delete Resource

Also if you want to get resource and you are supposed to send the sensitive data then it is always good that you pass that data in body instead of passing as an paramter in URL